# UiCollectionviewcell transform scale when selected in TVOS

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos, uicollectionviewlayout, apple-tv

I want to have the facilities to show a bigger cell when selected in UICollectionView.

I am doing this using the below code, its doing its task, what I want, that all cell that are in left and right to the selected cell will be slided to left and right so that selected cell will have a bigger size.

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
if let prev = context.previouslyFocusedView as? ShowListCollectionViewCell
        {

            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
               prev?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
}, completion: nil)
}
 if let next = context.nextFocusedView as? ShowListCollectionViewCell
        {
coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({


                next.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1)
 }, completion: nil)
```

So if put the scale to 1.1 from 1.0 then its okay. If I want a bigger size, like 1.5 then its covering the its right cell. which I dont want, I want cells of right and left hand to be slided to give the selected cell space.